# Can't display images in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I can't display images in JSP (and can't access other things like external Javascript/jQuery through SRC). The following JSP page just contains one `<img>` tag that can not display the image located by the SRC.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Temp.htm" method="post">
            <img src="/images/temp.jpg" alt="Not available">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The images are in `/WEB-INF/jsp/images`. I have also tried to change the image location and ensure all the times that the path given to SRC is correct still it didn't. <s>The same is possible with the applications without the framework. It works there perfectly.</s> What am I missing here?

Comment: You should start by realizing that this has absolutely nothing to do with Spring and Hibernate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, `/WEB-INF` is not accessible from the outside.

Second, if you use `/images/temp.jpg`, the browser will load images from the root of the web server, and not from the root of your web-app (which is deployed under a context path).

Use the JSTL `<c:url>` tag to generate absolute paths from the root of the web-app:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/images/temp.jpg'/>" alt=.../>
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access files that are located in `/WEB-INF/` directly from the web. The folder is protected from web access.

Locate your image files somewhere else. `/images/temp.jpg` is a absolute path, however you likely need a relative one. Point your image path to `image/temp.jpg` and place the images in the `/images/` folder directly located under your web root. E.g. `WebContent/images` or `src/main/webapp/images` (depending on your web root).

Answer (score 2):

Try put in the webapp directory, not WEB-INF. Obv. dont nest in the jsp dir.