# How to configure Java Servlet running in a Tomcat container to serve an HTML file (without JSP)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I would like to configure a simple Tomcat container to serve HTML files.  Note that this question is very similar to this old question:

[Can't display images in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366430/cant-display-images-in-jsp)

However, I would like to not use JSP if at all possible, because it seems like a dying technology and I do not want to invest a lot of time learning something on the way out.

HomeServlet.java:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/webapp/html/home.html");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

        // do nothing bc idk what I'm doing

    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.rigatron.rigs4jj.Servlets.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: Directory Structure (note location of the home.html file)]

I've encountered a similar problem before, which is when I just used the solution I linked above.  But I don't want to use JSP for this project.  Is there a way to configure Tomcat's default directory so that I can know where my paths are relative to at runtime?

By the way, I should mention that this application is meant to be deployed on Heroku.  The way that Heroku deploys Tomcat apps is with a jar wrapper thing called "webapp-runner".  Here is the maven description of that dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
              <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
              <version>8.5.11.3</version>
              <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And I run my app locally with the command "java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war".

Comment: Have you tried to do it already? Because by default it also serves html files.

Comment: Yes, all the code I posted is real.  When I try to run the application Tomcat overflows the console with errors, and repeatedly talks about some stack overflow occurring.

Comment: how about having a try to change the `request.getRequestDispatcher("/webapp/html/home.html");` to `request.getRequestDispatcher("/html/home.html");`

Comment: I tried that, and many other path guesses, but I haven't had any luck.  I think it might be related to Tomcat contexts which I've never had a look at:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Whats the actual question? Put html files into the webapp directory, there's no need for any code.

Comment: @Stefan I want to use the servlet to forward to the HTML pages, and then communicate between the servlet and views via JS AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet `com.rigatron.rigs4jj.Servlets.HomeServlet` handles all requests (including requests for static content like `index.html`).

So delete servlet from `web.xml` or change its servlet mapping. And then Tomcat will serve your static context.

Comment: I want to use the servlet to forward to the HTML pages, and then communicate between the servlet and views via JS AJAX calls.  I'm not totally sure that this is possible, but that's what my original vision was.

Comment: I would recommend use just one servlet for API calls <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>. Tomcat will serve context files automatically.If you specifically needs handle static context by yourself use second servlet for static context <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> which will handles all other request.