# The jsp project deployment image cannot be loaded

Tags: java

There is no problem running the project on my idea, and then I packaged it into a war file and tried to deploy it locally, but when I visited, I found that the picture could not be displayed. This is my project structure and running result
[image]

[image]

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div style="border-radius: 30px;border: solid deepskyblue; width: 350px;">
        <h3>toy family</h3>
        <form action="./ShowServlet" method="post">
            toy name：<input type="text" name="key">
            <button type="submit">search</button><br><br>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>toy name</td>
                    <td>price</td>
                    <td>image</td>
                    <td>operate</td>
                </tr>
        <c:set var="proList" value="${requestScope.proList}"/>
        <c:forEach var="pl" items="${proList}">
            <tr>
                <td>${pl.PName}</td>
                <td>${pl.price}</td>
                <td><img src="\img\${pl.img}" width="40" height="40" alt=""></td>
                <td><a href='DelServlet?id=${pl.id}'>delete</a><br><a href='modify.jsp?id=${pl.id}&PName=${pl.PName}&price=${pl.price}&filename=${pl.img}'>modify</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${empty proList}">
            <c:redirect url="/ShowServlet"/>
        </c:if>
            </table>
        </form>
        <a href="add.jsp">add</a>
        <a href="main.jsp">return</a>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the absolute path but it still can’t be displayed. I wonder if something is missing in the packaging process. I don’t know if the out directory is necessary.

Comment: JSP doesn't magically allow you to include static resources. Those need to be packaged with the app and served along with the JSP files, probably using some static file servlet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't display images in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366430/cant-display-images-in-jsp)

Comment: forward slash vs backwards slash?

Comment: @seenukarthi First of all, thanks for answering. I don’t think it’s solved. It’s because the img is placed in the web-imf directory and it’s unrecognizable. The idea I put in the same directory runs fine, but it’s a problem after packaging and deploying.